# Как использовать округление ответа в большую сторону в моем коде?

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

значит мне нужно получить результат с 3 цифрами после запятой, как сделать округление я знаю `round(elem,3)`, но конкретно в моем случае нет

скажите, куда поставить `round` в код чтобы ответ выдавал с 3 цифрами после запятой

```
A = (5.5, 3.5)
B = (1.5,2)
print(f'Длина = {((B[0]-A[0]) ** 2 + (B[1]-A[1]) ** 2) ** 0.5:.2f}')
```

Comment: Создавать вопросы, которые будет сложно найти, на этом ресурсе бессмысленно. Давайте код текстом.

Comment: @vp_arth сейчас исправлю

Comment: Непонятно, с чего вы взяли, что ответ вообще нужно округлять. И тем более, зачем вы выводите результат с двумя знаками, когда вам нужно с тремя.

Comment: @vp_arth я и прошу в задании округлить до 3 знаков

Comment: @vp_arth в большую сторону

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разделите действия, код должно быть легко читать.
Вычисление результата отдельно, формат вывода отдельно:

```
L = ((B[0]-A[0])**2+(B[1]-A[1])**2)**0.5;

print(f'Длина = {round(L, 3)}')
# или
print(f'Длина = {L:.3f}') # по аналогии с тем, что у вас было до этого
```

Можно заэкстрактить ещё несколько переменных, чтобы было ещё понятнее:

```
dx = B[0] - A[0]
dy = B[1] - A[1]
l = (dx*dx + dy*dy) ** 0.5
```

Comment: в первой строке где `**0.5;` подчеркивает красным и пишет ошибка

Comment: Вот, именно поэтому код должно быть легко читать) Исправил косяк со скобкой, и дописал ниже, как это должно выглядеть)

Answer (score 1):

```
A = (2, 4)
B = (4, 1)
print(f'Длина = {((B[0]-A[0]) ** 2 + (B[1]-A[1]) ** 2) ** 0.5:.3f}')

Длина = 3.606
```

???

Comment: я ошибся с данными, другие поставил из примера, проверьте их

Comment: @марат, а самому проверить никак их? Все работает как и должно.

Comment: я проверял и выдало 2 знака после запятой)) выше ответили и теперь заработало, а до этого нет

Comment: @марат, значит неверно проверяли. Код выдает ответ "Длина = 4.272"

Comment: @марат, если внимательно смотреть на мой код, можно заметить исправление с .2f на .3f. Вот из-за того, что вы мой код не запускали у вас и вышло 2 цифры после запятой.